# How do I use gantt charts in superset

Tags: apache-superset, gantt-chart

The original superset does not support drawing gantt charts, but I have a need to draw gantt charts, how do I extend superset?

I have searched some resources, but I can't seem to find the relevant extension tutorial

I want to extend the superset plugin to chart gantt charts